# Format '%[^_' expects argument of type 'char *' but argument 3 has type 'char(*)[(sizetype)(s)]'

Tags: c

I am receiving a warning in the for statement:

```
for (; p < p_end && sscanf(p, "%[^_]%n", &buf, &n); p += (n+1))
```

Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void find_integers(const char* p) {
    size_t s = strlen(p)+1;
    char buf[s];
    const char * p_end = p+s;
    int n;
    /* tokenize string */
    for (; p < p_end && sscanf(p, "%[^_]%n", &buf, &n); p += (n+1))
    {
        int x;
        /* try to parse an integer */
        if (sscanf(buf, "%d", &x)) {
            printf("got int :) %d\n", x);
        }
        else {
            printf("got str :( %s\n", buf);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    const char *  line = "Foo_bar_Baz_23_25_27";
    find_integers(line);
}
```

Trying to use above code am getting this warning:

```
Format '%[^_' expects argument of type 'char *' but argument 3 has type 'char(*)[(sizetype)(s)]'
```

How would I get rid of this warning?  Thank You.

Comment: `p += (n+1)` looks dodgy.  Suggest `for ( ; sscanf(p, "%[^_] %n", &buf, &n) == 1; p += n)`.  Mind the `" %n", == 1, n /* + nothing*/`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error message states, the `%[` format specifier expects a `char *` as an argument, but the argument you're passing, i.e. `&buf`, has type  `char (*)[s]`, i.e. a pointer to a variable length array.

An array decays into a pointer to its first element in most expressions, so get rid of the `&` on the argument.

```
for (; p < p_end && sscanf(p, "%[^_]%n", buf, &n); p += (n+1))
```

Comment: Thank you that fixed it!  What is the main difference in passing a parameter using the & and not using it?  Thank you.

Comment: @RobertSmith The `&` operator takes the address of its operand.  The `scanf` format specifiers expect the address of some variable to populate.  In the case of `%s` and `%[`, that address is the address of the first member of an array.